# Laravel 6.2 - Dynamically Call a Controller action

Tags: laravel

I have used a code from Internet to call controller action dynamically. Here is the code for that, and is used in `web.php`. But I dont fully understand what it does.

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '{controller}/{action?}/{params1?}/{params2?}', function ($controller, $action = 'index', $params1 = '',$params2 = '') {

    $params = explode('/', $params1);
    $params[1] = $params2;
    $app = app();
    $controller = $app->make("\App\Http\Controllers\\" . ucwords($controller) . 'Controller');
    return $controller->callAction($action, $params);
})->middleware('supadminauth');
```

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '{controller}/{action?}/{params1?}/{params2?}', function ($controller, $action = 'index', $params1 = '',$params2 = '') {
```

The first line looks at the request to see whether it is a get or post request, if it is some other types of request that means it does not match and will not proceed further. Then the url are separated into 4 parts corresponding by their name and passed into variables with the same name i.e. $controller, $action, $param1 and $params2 where the last 3 variables do not need to be present (with ? at the end of the name).

```
$params = explode('/', $params1);
$params[1] = $params2;
```

I believe this is a crude way to create an array of parameters as `$params` where the following would be more appropriate.

```
$params = [$params1, $params2];
```

.

```
$app = app();
$controller = $app->make("\App\Http\Controllers\\" . ucwords($controller) . 'Controller');
```

Then load the relevant controller.

```
return $controller->callAction($action, $params);
```

And run the corresponding action and passing all the parameters with it.
Hope this makes sense.

Comment: you can call the Controller directly: 
`app("\App\Http\Controllers\\".$ControllerName)->callAction($action, $params);`

Answer (score 1):

This is example of use it:

If you have controller like bellow:

```
class AdminController extends Controller {

   public function index(){ //sample 0, sample 1
        ...
   }
    
   public function view($param1){ //sample2 , sample3
        ...
   }
}
```

There is some sample route for calling them

```
sample0: yoursite.com/admin
sample1: yoursite.com/admin/index
sample2: yoursite.com/admin/view    
sample3: yoursite.com/admin/view/5
```

Notice in your question `?` in `{action?}` means it can either have value or not. Other things is simple and clear. Do you need more explaination?